# Uso de LastInsertId() mais de uma vez

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, id

estou precisando de usar o lastInsertId() mais de uma vez em minha aplicação. Segue um exemplo de tal acontecimento:

```
<?php
//CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx","xxx","xxx");

//VARIÁVEIS COM DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
$senhaConfirm = $_POST["senhaConfirm"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$rua = $_POST["rua"];
$bairro = $_POST["bairro"];
$numero = $_POST["numero"];
$cidade = $_POST["cidade"];
$estado = $_POST["estado"];
$cep = $_POST["cep"];
$complemento = $_POST["complemento"];
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$nomeMercado = $_POST["nomeMercado"];
$cnpj = $_POST["cnpj"];
$telefoneMercado = $_POST["telefoneMercado"];
$celularMercado = $_POST["celularMercado"];
$expedienteInicio = $_POST["expedienteInicio"];
$expedienteFim = $_POST["expedienteFim"];
$arquivo = $_POST["arquivo"];

//INICIO DA TRANSAÇÃO
$pdo->beginTransaction();

//INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA ENDEREÇO
$insertEndereco = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ENDERECO(BAIRRO, CEP, CIDADE, COMPLEMENTO, ESTADO, NUMERO, RUA) VALUES(:bairro, :cep, :cidade, :complemento, :estado, :numero, :rua)");  
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":bairro",$bairro);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":cep",$cep);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":cidade",$cidade);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":complemento",$complemento);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":estado",$estado);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":numero",$numero);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":rua",$rua);
$insertEndereco->execute();
//VERIFICA SE A INSERÇÃO DE DADOS DE ENDEREÇO RETORNA TRUE(FOI REALIZADA)
if (!$insertEndereco) {
    die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seu endereço, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
}
$cod_endereco = $pdo->lastInsertId();//O LAST_

//INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA USUARIO
$insertUsuario = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO USUARIOS(COD_ENDERECO, NOME_USUARIO, E-MAIL_USUARIO, SENHA_USUARIO, TELEFONE, CELULAR,  TIPO_USUARIO,) VALUES(:cod_endereco,:nome,:email, :senha, :telefone, :celular, :usuario)"); 
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":cod_endereco",$cod_endereco); 
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":email",$email);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":senha",$senha);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":telefone",$telefone);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":celular",$celular);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario);
$insertEndereco->execute();
if (!$insertUsuario) {
    die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seus dados pessoais, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
}
$cod_usuario = $pdo->lastInsertId();

//INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA SUPERMERCADO
$insertMercado = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO SUPERMERCADO (CNPJ, NOME, FOTO_SUPERMERCADO, INICIO_EXPEDIENTE,                 
    FIM_EXPEDIENTE, TELEFONE) VALUES (:cod_endereco_mercado, :cod_usuario, :cnpj, :nomeMercado, :arquivo, :expedienteInicio, :expedienteFim, :$telefoneMercado)");
    $insertMercado->bindValue(":cod_endereco_mercado",$pdo->lastInsertId());
    $insertMercado->bindValue(":cod_usuario",$cod_usuario);  
$insertMercado->bindValue(":cnpj",$cnpj);
$insertMercado->bindValue(":nomeMercado",$nomeMercado);
$insertMercado->bindValue(":arquivo",$arquivo);
$insertMercado->bindValue(":expedienteInicio",$expedienteInicio);
$insertMercado->bindValue(":expedienteFim",$expedienteFim);
$insertMercado->bindValue(":telefoneMercado",$telefoneMercado);
$insertMercado->execute();
//CASO TENHA DADO ALGUM ERRO NA TRANSAÇÃO rollBack IRÁ CANCELAR TODAS ELAS
if (!$insertMercado) {
        $pdo->rollBack();
        die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seu mercado, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
}
//FINALIZANDO TRANSAÇÃO
$pdo->commit(); 
echo($cod_endereco);
echo($cod_usuario);
echo($usuario); ?>
```

Fazendo dessa forma, só consigo capturar o primeiro valor do lastInsertId().
Alguém saberia me dizer como faço para conseguir capturar os valores de ambos?

Comment: Basta rodar o comando `$pdo->execute`()` pra cada operação e recuperar o id atraves de `$pdo->lastInsertId()`

Comment: Já estou fazendo isto, vou editar meu código para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que não está dando um execute no `$insertUsuario` e sim dois executes no `$insertEndereco`.

Ou seja, vc faz o primeiro execute no `$insertEndereco` e depois você está fazendo novamente dando um `bindValue em ":celular" e ":usuario"` que não existem para o endereço, assim está gerando erro no insert e o pdo está retornando o id do primeiro insert que teve sucesso.

Na parte onde está:

```
//INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA USUARIO
$insertUsuario = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO USUARIOS(COD_ENDERECO, NOME_USUARIO, E-MAIL_USUARIO, SENHA_USUARIO, TELEFONE, CELULAR,  TIPO_USUARIO,) VALUES(:cod_endereco,:nome,:email, :senha, :telefone, :celular, :usuario)"); 
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":cod_endereco",$cod_endereco); 
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":email",$email);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":senha",$senha);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":telefone",$telefone);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":celular",$celular);
$insertEndereco->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario);
$insertEndereco->execute();
if (!$insertUsuario) {
    die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seus dados pessoais, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
}
$cod_usuario = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Acho que teria que ser:

```
//INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA USUARIO
$insertUsuario = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO USUARIOS(COD_ENDERECO, NOME_USUARIO, E-MAIL_USUARIO, SENHA_USUARIO, TELEFONE, CELULAR,  TIPO_USUARIO,) VALUES(:cod_endereco,:nome,:email, :senha, :telefone, :celular, :usuario)"); 
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":cod_endereco",$cod_endereco); 
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":email",$email);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":senha",$senha);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":telefone",$telefone);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":celular",$celular);
$insertUsuario->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario);
$insertUsuario->execute();
if (!$insertUsuario) {
    die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seus dados pessoais, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
}
$cod_usuario = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Ah deus, é vdd, que moleee!
Obrigado!!!

Comment: Bom que deu certo, abrass

Comment: Engraçado que mesmo eu dando um echo no cod_endereço e jogando ele no insert pra popular a tabela usuário, não esta dando certo...